# PostgreSQL - Creating a loop with a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have these Stored Procedure logic to be implemented:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_array(arraynumbers integer[])
RETURNS TABLE (name text) AS $$
DECLARE 
index integer := 0
BEGIN 
FOREACH index < arraynumbers
LOOP
SELECT e.name as empname FROM employee as e
WHERE e.id = arraynumbers[index]
LIMIT 1
name.push(empname)
ENDLOOP;
RETURN name;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The goal is to loop based on the length of the array parameter and every index of the parameter will be the condition for retrieving a record and push it to a variable and return the variable as table.

What is the correct way of writing it in PostgreSQL Stored Procedure?

Comment: What do you expect the non-existing `push()` method to do?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name I wanted to append the result of the SELECT (which is a single record) to a variable in every loop.

Comment: But you declared the function as `returns table` so why are you appending everything to a single (non-existing) variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what exactly the result should be, but as far as I can tell, you don't need a loop or a PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_array(arraynumbers integer[])
  RETURNS TABLE (name text) 
AS 
$$
  SELECT e.name 
  FROM employee as e
  WHERE e.id = any(arraynumbers);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This will return one row for each id in `arraynumbers` that exist in the employee table. As the function is declared as `returns table` there is no need  to collect the values into a single variable (which you didn't declare to begin with)

Comment: I will try to implement this answer. If this answer solves the problem, I will indicate this as the correct answer.